# Android - Creating ImageViews/Button/Textviews not defined in Xml

Tags: android

I need to create a number of ImageViews (or alternate methods of showing images) depending on user input and also arrange them in a circular fashion.

I am unsure where to start and I couldnt possibly define them in the xml layout file as I have no idea how many i need to create.

How do I go about setting this up?

Comment: take a user input , pass it to switch case and create dynamic view content

Comment: You can use a grid view to set images dynamically. For a fair idea on this you can refer this link.http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html

Comment: Have You tried to create custom ViewGroup (google can help to find lot of examples on the subject)?